# sql to grab specific info from meta field

Tags: sql

Don't know if I am phrasing that correctly.  Here is the situation.  When a 'feature' image is added to the content it is being saved in a meta_value field in the database along with a lot of other stuff.  I want to pull just the image data from the field to use it in the content elsewhere...

How do I structure the sql query to get just the image data.  This is how the info exists in the meta_value field

```
"event_thumbnail_url";s:87:"http://nameofsite.info/venue1-atrium2.jpg";s:13:
```

I have this query in place that pulls *all* the data in that field:

```
SELECT e.id, e.event_name, e.start_date, e.event_desc, e.venue_title, 
e.registration_start, e.registration_end, e.event_meta 
FROM " . et_events_detail . " e  
WHERE (e.registration_start <= date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
AND (e.registration_end >= date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Any help - greatly apreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to split the string and extract the `"http://nameofsite.info/venue1-atrium2.jpg"` part? If so, I'm not sure whether that can be done without using a function. What DB engine are you using?

Comment: Forgive me - DB engine?  I was thinking the same thing.  New to writing the functions thing but was looking in that direction.

Comment: By DB engine I mean database management system (I should avoid saying DB engine). Examples would be MySQL, PostgreSQL, Ms SQL Server, etc etc. There are a few helpful links are SO, but I don't want to post any if they are not for your DB system.

Comment: This might help. Lots of string functions in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the resource...  see what i can get done;-)